# If roots of equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is $\alpha,\beta$ find the roots of equation $bcx^2+a(bc+a^2)x+ac^2=0$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If roots of equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is $\alpha,\beta$ find the roots of equation $bcx^2+a(bc+a^2)x+ac^2=0$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta$

**My Try:**

We know that

$$\alpha+\beta=-\frac ba \quad  \text{ and } \quad \alpha  \beta=\frac ca$$

I have tried to substitute $\alpha,\beta$ into the new equation, but I have faced some trouble how to separate roots,

So far I got;

$$x^2+\bigg(\frac {1}{\alpha\beta}-\frac {1}{(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha\beta)^2}\bigg)x+\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}=0$$

How to proceed? If you suggest a completely different method that is fine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you mean $ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: ... and are you sure about the coefficient of $x^2$ being only total degree 2 in $a,b,c$ but the coefficients of $x,1$ are total degree 3?

Comment: oh srry my mistake ill edit

Comment: one obvious method is to find the roots of the final equation you got using the quadratic formula

Comment: @user10354138 Your question is not clear to me. I have done the edit as Hari Ramakrishnan Sudhakar mentioned

Comment: Maybe it's easier to use Vieta's theorem?

Comment: The quadratic equation you have got in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ does not seem correct. You may have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @emil if you doubled $a,b,c$ the roots $\alpha,\beta$ of $ax^2+bx+c$ are unchanged, but the roots of your new quadratic $bcx^2+a(bc+a^2)x+ac^2$ changes (note the coefficient of $x^2$ will be quadrupled but the coefficient of $x,1$ will get multiplied by 8).  So the roots are not determined by $\alpha,\beta$ alone.

Answer (score 1):

The given quadratic equation has the roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then we have that
$$ \alpha + \beta = -\frac{b}{a} \quad \text{ and } \quad \alpha \cdot \beta = \frac{c}{a} $$
The new quadratic $$ bc \cdot x^2 + a(bc + a^2)x + ac^2 = 0  $$
$\blacksquare~$**What I have so far:**

Let the roots of the new quadratic be $m, n$. Then we have that
$$ m + n = -a \cdot \frac{bc + a^2}{bc} = - a\bigg(1 + \frac{a^2}{bc}\bigg) = - a \cdot {\bigg(1 - \color{red}{ \frac{1}{\alpha \beta (\alpha + \beta)}}\bigg)} $$
and $$ mn = \frac{ac^2}{bc} = \frac{a}{b} \cdot c = - a \cdot \bigg( \frac{\alpha \beta}{ \alpha + \beta} \bigg)  $$
Hence the quadratic has become $$ x^2 + a \cdot \bigg(1 - \color{red}{\frac{1}{\alpha \beta (\alpha + \beta)}}\bigg) x  - a \cdot \bigg( \frac{\alpha \beta}{ \alpha + \beta} \bigg) = 0 $$
I haven't found out any way to calculate and substitute $a$ yet (it seems too that we can't determine the roots just by $\alpha$ and $\beta$).

Comment: Please check, your expression for $m+n$ is not correct.

Comment: Edited @DrZafarAhmedDSc